# Visual Studio 2013 Deployment "database does not exist or contains no mapped tables." fault

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, deployment

You can see the below information about my deployment

1. AutoMigration= true
2. I have created a database in server.
3. I select the deploy option with right click to my project, and select my DB server and database.
4. It has successfully uploaded and deployed my application.

Here is my connection string after deployment to the server :

```
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=**.***.***.***;Initial Catalog=MyDatB;User ID=sa;Password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And here is my migration config

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    ContextKey = "ModulericaV1.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
}
```

But i got the following error when i am trying to launch my application :

> Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the
>   database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations
>   to create the database and its tables, for example by running the
>   'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

Please note : If i did not create my database in development server, my codefirst application is not going to create database for me .. It is also problem i think.

Comment: are you sure you need the ContextKey? What happens when you run 'Update-Database' from the PM console (with connection string to server)? error message?

Comment: Actually, i did not insert the context key there ? What does it means ? I will try to perform update-database also soon